# Auto shut down during startup update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Yesterday I turned on my new laptop. The windows 10 said it needs some update before starting into the OS.

Suddenly it was shut down by itself during updating. Pressing the power button resumes the update procedure and nothing abnormal happens afterwards.

Is it normal for Windows to shut itself during a startup update? Or should I worry about my own computer? Or does that sound like hitting the power button accidentally? Thanks!

Comment: It's totally normal for Windows to restart after an update. And if you decide to shutdown, Windows will also update sometimes before it shuts itself off. This can also be managed in your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does shut down automatically during some of its OS updates.  If this happens again after the update process, then something is amiss which may not necessarily be related to the update process; in which case, further investigation/observation may be necessary to determine the cause of such incident.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)